# Uncaught ReferenceError: height is not defined - Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

First of all, I am completely new to Backbone.js and I am using [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/joeartsea/KjYqf/) to learn.

I am trying to get values from a text input and create models from the input. The template should be loaded and the attribute `height` from each model should be displayed on the same HTML.

I am able to create models and add them to a collection since I see `n {length: 105, models: Array[105], _byId: Object}` in console.log(Sections). However, (I'm guessing) when I try to load the template, it is giving me the error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: height is not defined'. I am thinking if I am getting the attributes incorrectly.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Here is the template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="section-template">
    <div class="view">
       <label><%- height %></label>
       <label><%- color %></label>
       <a class="destroy"></a>
    </div>
</script>
```

Model:

```
var Section = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function(){
        return {
            height: 200,
            color: ''
        };
    }
});
```

Model Collection:

```
var SectionList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Section,
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("sections-backbone")
});
var Sections = new SectionList;
```

Model View & event action:

```
var SectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:  "li",
    template: _.template($("#section-template").html()),
    initialize: function() {
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Make Application:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#sectionboard"),
    events: {
        "keypress #new-height":  "createOnEnter"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.input = this.$("#new-height");
        this.main = $("#main");
        Sections.fetch();
    },
        createOnEnter: function(e) {
         if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
         if (!this.input.val()) return;
         Sections.create({height: this.input.val(), color: '#FFFFFF'});
         this.input.val("");

         console.log(Sections);

         var view = new SectionView({model: Sections});
         this.$("#section-list").append(view.render().el);

      }
});
var App = new AppView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
var view = new SectionView({model: Sections});
```

`Sections` is a collection, but you're telling the view it's a model, so there's a conflict there.

Comment: @Tholle Just did. Thanks for the tips! :)

Comment: @Tholle appreciate it, i hate begging for points. Alvin have fun with backbone, i've been using it for a couple weeks and it's really great.